# Call function to a non parent object

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Lets say I have a QML that contains this:

```
MainView {
    id: main
    Component {
        MyItem {
            // has function doSomething()
            id: item
            function doSomething() // this will work
            Child {
                function parent.doSomething() // this too
                function item.doSomething() // and this
            }
        }
    }
    Page {
        // here is where I would like to be able to call the function
    }
}
```

I'm unable to call the function `doSomething()` from anything that's not a child, is it possible to call it for example from inside the `Page {}` object?

I'm sorry for the question being so badly written, but I'm unsure of how to put it in another way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe this might work @zeokila you coud try calling the main parent and then decending down to the child where the function resides.

Comment: Nope, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'anotherChild' of undefined` if I put for example `root.child.anotherChild`.

Comment: Is 'Component' used here on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you wrapped into a Component item, which acts like a separated file sandboxing the var/function scope. So from inside the component you can access the outside but the opposite is impossible. 
The only trick to acheive what you're trying to do would be to declare a signal in an outside element, add a Connections item inside your component and fire you signal when you need to trigger the inner function.